# Decrease spacing between two rows in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two rows and each row contains 4 columns. Each column consists of some type of input box (either drop-down or normal text box).

My 1st row has two fields which has certain description associated with it as well and this description appears at the bottom of the input box.

In my 2nd row, I want to place an input box only in the third column (and not in the 1/2/4th column). I have been able to accomplish all this part, however, there seems to be some extra spacing between the 1st and the 2nd row (3rd column box named `E`). Can I decrease it somehow? Attached is the picture. [image]

Basically, I want `E` to appear on same level below `C` at the level of the description `fully qualified name` and not so much below.

Here is the HTML code I have:

```
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="12">
          <b-row>
            <b-col :cols="3" >
              <b-row>
                <!-- Label -->
                <b-col :cols="4">
                  <br>
                  <span class="inpCap"> A </span>
                </b-col>
                <!-- Input -->
                <b-col :cols="8">
                  <div>
                    <b-form-group description="Hold Shift/Ctrl to select multiple values">
                      <multiselect :multiple="true" v-model="form.severity" :options="severityOptions" track-by="text" label="text"
                                   :select-label="'Select'"
                                   :deselect-label="'Unselect'"
                      ></multiselect>
                    </b-form-group>
                  </div>
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
            <!---->
            <!-- Right Column -->
            <b-col :cols="3">
              <!-- Intro Commit ID -->
              <b-row>
                <!-- Label -->
                <b-col :cols="4">
                  <span class="inpCap"> B </span>
                </b-col>
                <!-- Input -->
                <b-col :cols="8">
                  <b-form-group id="intro_commit_idGroup"
                                description="fully qualified name">
                    <b-form-input id="intro_commit_id"
                                  type="text"
                                  v-model="form.tag"
                                  placeholder="Enter">
                    </b-form-input>
                    <br>
                  </b-form-group>
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
            <b-col :cols="3">
              <!-- Region-->
              <b-row>
                <!-- Label -->
                <b-col :cols="4">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 h-100">
                    <span class="inpCap"> C </span>
                  </div>
                </b-col>
                <!-- Input -->
                <b-col :cols="8">
                  <div>
                    <multiselect
                      id="region"
                      v-model="form.region"
                      :options="regionOptions"
                      :multiple="true"
                      :select-label="'Select'"
                      :deselect-label="'Unselect'"
                      @input="resetVenue()"
                    ></multiselect>
                  </div>
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
              <!---->
            </b-col>
            <b-col :cols="3">
              <b-row>
                <b-col :cols="4">
                </b-col>
                <!-- Input -->
                <b-col :cols="8">
                  <div>
                    <b-button v-if="!this.show"  type="button" @click="submit" variant="primary" size=""> D </b-button>
                  </div>
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>

      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="12">
          <b-row>
            <b-col :cols="3" >
            </b-col>
            <b-col :cols="3" >
            </b-col>
            <b-col :cols="3" >
              <b-row>
                <!-- Label -->
                <b-col :cols="4">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 h-100">
                    <span class="inpCap"> E </span>
                  </div>
                </b-col>
                <!-- Input -->
                <b-col :cols="8">
                  <b-form-input id="repo"
                                type="text"
                                v-model="form.repo"
                                placeholder="Enter"
                                style="width: 85% !important;"
                  >
                  </b-form-input>
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try creating a row in the 3rd column(C) itself so that it will occupy the same height as the 1st parent row which contains A, B and C.

So basically you will add C & E together in the 3rd column with self adjusting height as you want wrt columns 1 and 2 (A and B).